# Select specific fields with left outer join in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

How to select specific fields from left collection along with left outer join to some collection

```
  db.users.aggregate(
{

$lookup:
    {
        from: 'vehicles',
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "vehicleBelongsTo",
        as: "mapping"
     }
 }
 )
```

In this query I'm also getting password field how to exclude it or How can I select specific fields from users collection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) operator to project all of the fields you need, like this:

```js
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "vehicles",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "vehicleBelongsTo",
      as: "mapping"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: { 
      name:1,
      email:1,
      // List all of the fields you need here.
      //
      // Probably show only "vehicles_name" from mapping.
      // If you need the full mapping, then use `mapping: 1`
      "mapping.vehicles_name":1
    }
  }
]);
```